# Error while login Power Portal using Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, powerapps, dynamics-crm-online, azureportal, power-platform

I am using Power Portal Azure AD B2C for login with external account. but after login I got this error message (I have disable custom error from power platform admin settings)

[image]

My Azure B2C portal SignIn user flow claims are as follows.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Usman, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT the problem is related to security time stamp  (which i was not setting in Contact Entity while creating Portal User from CRM Workflow), i have updated my CRM Workflow and Add Security TimeStamp and everything is working now. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

•   The error that you are encountering while logging in with the external account to the Azure AD B2C power app portal can be resolved by verifying the following settings correctly in the **‘web.config’** file of your app: -

a)  `The ‘ida:SignInPolicyId’ app key exists, and you've replaced the value with the name of the Sign-in policy that you provided in the Azure B2C Admin Portal`.

b)  `The ‘ida:PasswordResetPolicyId’ app key exists, and you've replaced the value with the name of the Sign-in policy that you provided in the Azure B2C Admin Portal`.

c)  `The ‘ida:UserProfilePolicyId’ app key exists, and you've replaced the value with the name of the Sign-in policy that you provided in the Azure B2C Admin Portal. Post modifications of the ‘web.config’ file` with the above settings, it should resemble as below: -

```
  <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="ida:SignInPolicyId" value="B2C_Signin_Policy">
     <add key="ida:PasswordResetPolicyId" value="B2C_PasswordReset_Policy">
      <add key="ida:UserProfilePolicyId" value="B2C_UserProfile_Policy">
        ...
      </appSettings>
```

•   Also ensure that the value for **‘Authentication/OpenIdConnect/[Federation-Name]/Authority’** setting is correct. For that, you will have to **open the metadata and get the correct ‘Issuer’ value** and update it accordingly.

For more information, kindly refer to the documentation links below and update the settings correctly as per the below documentation: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/server-error-application-exception

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/portals/configure/azure-ad-b2c